# sum values in rows mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to sum the values from the indiviual rows in this query?
I've made bold the idea I had but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
    `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_id` AS `pay_id`,
    `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_month` AS `pay_month`,
    GROUP_CONCAT((CASE
            WHEN (`view_monthly_bills`.`bill_type` = 'Mortgage') THEN `view_monthly_bills`.`debit`
            ELSE NULL
        END)
        SEPARATOR ',') AS `Mortgage`,
    GROUP_CONCAT((CASE
            WHEN (`view_monthly_bills`.`bill_type` = 'Shopping') THEN `view_monthly_bills`.`debit`
            ELSE NULL
        END)
        SEPARATOR ',') AS `Shopping`,
    GROUP_CONCAT((CASE
            WHEN (`view_monthly_bills`.`bill_type` = 'TV') THEN `view_monthly_bills`.`debit`
            ELSE NULL
        END)
        SEPARATOR ',') AS `TV`,
        **SUM( Mortgage + Shopping + TV)**
FROM
    `view_monthly_bills`
GROUP BY `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_id` , `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_month`
ORDER BY `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_id` DESC
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *It doesn't work* is not a very useful problem statement. What goes wrong? Do you get an error message? Do you get numerically incorrect results, or absent results?

Comment: You cannot reference an alias that way. I'm afraid the most efficient solution is to write it all out longhand again

Comment: please provide some sample rows and what you would like them to do. We could guess which ones are integers but shouldn't have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use `case` statement with `OR` and function agregation `SUM`:

```
SELECT 
    `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_id` AS `pay_id`,
    `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_month` AS `pay_month`,
    GROUP_CONCAT((CASE
            WHEN (`view_monthly_bills`.`bill_type` = 'Mortgage') THEN `view_monthly_bills`.`debit`
            ELSE NULL
        END)
        SEPARATOR ',') AS `Mortgage`,
    GROUP_CONCAT((CASE
            WHEN (`view_monthly_bills`.`bill_type` = 'Shopping') THEN `view_monthly_bills`.`debit`
            ELSE NULL
        END)
        SEPARATOR ',') AS `Shopping`,
    GROUP_CONCAT((CASE
            WHEN (`view_monthly_bills`.`bill_type` = 'TV') THEN `view_monthly_bills`.`debit`
            ELSE NULL
        END)
        SEPARATOR ',') AS `TV`,
        SUM((CASE
            WHEN (`view_monthly_bills`.`bill_type` = 'TV' OR
                `view_monthly_bills`.`bill_type` = 'Shopping' OR
                `view_monthly_bills`.`bill_type` = 'Mortgage'
                )THEN `view_monthly_bills`.`debit`
            ELSE 0
        END)) as sum_debit
FROM
    `view_monthly_bills`
GROUP BY `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_id` , `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_month`
ORDER BY `view_monthly_bills`.`pay_id` DESC
LIMIT 6
```